# Why my Ubuntu 18.04 dose not fit in my monitor/TV

Tags: ubuntu, display

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 and it does not fit in my monitor what is the fix your answer will be appreciated. 
I have an Intel i3 540 with integrated graphics card 4gb of ram 500gb of HDD

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't fit"?

Comment: I can not see the dock and the sides of the screen it is like it is zoomed I did not change it to autohide

Comment: TVs usually overscan, which basically pushes the edges of the picture outside the screen area. See if there's a setting on it that can swap overscan to P2P [pixel to pixel], it might be called 'computer mode' or something similar.

Comment: Ok Thanks appreciate it  my tv have that setting but it is called dot by dot thanks allot

Comment: I'll drop that in as an answer, for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TVs usually overscan, which basically pushes the edges of the picture outside the screen area.

See if there's a setting on it that can swap overscan to P2P [pixel to pixel], it might be called 'dot by dot' or just 'computer mode' or something similar.